# Why should you serve risotto on a hot plate?

Tags: rice, italian-cuisine, risotto

In many places it is said to "Serve risotto on a hot plate - or else" or "you better serve it on a hot plate".

Why is that so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What moscafj says is true, but it doesn't explain specifically for risotto.

Basically, the creaminess** is because of a starch-based solution.  Starch based solutions are temperature dependent and will get much thicker as it cools.  If there's enough starch, it can solidify to the point where the [sauce will break into pieces](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10855/67) if you try to manipulate it.

** Don't start with the 'it's not creamy because there isn't cream in it' crap again.

Comment: I would also add that anything liquid or semi-liquid will spread on the plate and have a large area of contact with the plate, and thus conduct heat very quickly and effectively into it, cooling quicker than solid foods would

Comment: @canardgras : an excellent point

Comment: @joe that is interesting Joe. Could that be the reason that when I combine my bechamel and pasta, the sauce breaks the day after?

Comment: @BarAkiva : breaks as in 'oil separates out' like a mayo breaking, or breaks as in 'it cracked in half'?  If it's the second, then yes.

Comment: breaks as in "oil separates out" and the sauce turns from creamy to grainy.

Comment: @BarAkiva : I've seen it happen when microwaved.  See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/8783/67 and maybe https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/79135/67

Answer (score 7):

Using hot plates allows food to retain it's heat between plating a service...also works with cold plates, if you want to keep something cold.